# What is the most semantically-correct HTML element for a form field hint/note?

Tags: html, forms, semantics

The label and the field are easy; we have `<label>` and then the relevant input field. But what is the most semantically-correct HTML element to use for the smaller informational text that goes under the field?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know of a specific element or attribute to connect them, but you can do so using the ARIA attribute `aria-describedby`:

```
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" aria-describedby="firstname-explanation" />
<p id="firstname-explanation">e.g. John</p>
```

But including everything in the `label` seems good to me either (also gives good styling abilities, as you have a  - semantic - container):

```
<label>
    <span class="form-item-title">First Name</span>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" />
    <span class="form-item-description">e.g. John</span>
</label>
```

Or you could even **mix the two**.

Another approach could be to put the description in the `title` (or `placeholder` as suggested by @Alohci) attribute of the `input` element (semantically this is the one describing it), but in this case you have to insert it to the markup through Javascript (or CSS using `input:after { content : "e.g. " attr(placeholder) }` - suggested by @Alohci).

Comment: That could work. I'll hold out for a while first in order to see if any HTML gurus with encyclopedic knowledge of the elements can give a definitive answer before I mark this one correct.

Comment: aria-describedby is a brave attempt, but it has a couple of problems. First, the HTML5 spec makes clear that aria attributes are *only* directives to the browser as to how the browser should expose content to the platform's accessibility API, and do not themselves convey semantic information. Second, examples are not descriptions. A ideal semantic solution might be to make the examples placeholder attributes and style them to be outside the input box as depicted in the question, but that's for the future, not now. For now, I would use a second `<label for="">` element.

Comment: @Alohci I agree with most things that you say. Though sometimes you can best describe something with an example (`placeholder` is still a valid idea, but has the same problem as `title` here). For best results, instead of your suggested 2 `label`s, I'd still go with one `label` around the whole thing (which is perfectly valid).

Comment: @bazmegakapa - Agreed. I'm not sure javascript is needed though. I had in mind something like, in css: `input:after { content : "e.g. " attr(placeholder) }`. That might, with additional positioning css do the trick.

Comment: @Alohci Yes, that's certainly a better way than Javascript (or will be when IE 7 dies :)). I add this to my answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the W3C's position on placing the input field inside the label tag?

Comment: @Nathan In the official [HTML4 spec about `label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) : `To associate a label with another control implicitly, the control element must be within the contents of the LABEL element.` The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) says the same.